# Proving that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix, then $\det(A) = \pm1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question on my assignment asking me to prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix, then $\det(A) = \pm1$. What I did so far is:

We know that $A\cdot A^t = I$ (since it is orthogonal), and that would mean that if $A$ is a matrix with elements $a,b,c,d$ then :

\begin{cases}a^2 + b^2 = 1\\
ac + bd = 0\\
c^2 + d^2 = 1\end{cases}

which implies that \begin{align}\det(A)&= ad - bc\\
&= -\frac{bd^2}{c} - cb\\
&= -\frac{bd^2}{c} - \frac{c^2b}{c}\\
&= -\frac{bd^2 + bc^2}{c}\\
&= -\frac{b(d^2 + c^2)}{c}\\
&= -\frac{b(1)}{c}\\
&= -b/c\end{align}

I might be doing something wrong here, could someone please help me out understand this?

Comment: The equation $A^t A=1$ implies $\det A \,\det A^T=1$, so $\det (A)\,\det(A)=1$, hence $(\det(A))^2=1$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A{A^T} = I \Rightarrow \det \left( {A{A^T}} \right) = \det \left( A \right)\det \left( {{A^T}} \right) = \det {\left( A \right)^2} = \det \left( I \right) = 1 \Rightarrow \det \left( A \right) =  \pm 1$

I'm using properties 1, 2 and 4 from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).

Comment: Not sure if I understand the part where you go from det(A)det(A transpose) = det(A)^2... wouldn't this mean that A = A transpose?

Comment: Yes, $\det \left( {{A^T}} \right) = \det \left( A \right)$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is orthogonal, $A^{-1} = A^T$. Hence ${1 \over \det A} = \det A^T = \det A$, which is $(\det A)^2 = 1$.